# foundry debug: unknown address at

Tags: contract-debugging, foundry

I use debug in foundry, but it doesn't show the contract. I have read these two issues, but doesn't work.[issues#2348](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/2348), [issues#2947](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/2947)

```
 forge debug --debug src/Counter.sol --sig "setMember()"
```

[image]